# Like Modal Dialog android

Tags: android, user-input, wait

I want to get the Gender of the user before he can continue using the program, thus, I used Asyc class

```
 class conectNet extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
```

I did first to avoid using network  inside main layout.
and then I Show a dialogue that asks the user to Identify his gender:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result){ // this method can use UI as mentioned in its docs
...

...
```

**the main point of my question**

I make dialogue and want to stop the thread until I get user response:

```
 ...
    ...
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SendRandom.this);
    builder.setTitle("gender");
     builder.setMessage(R.string.Gender_dialogQ); //Gender_dialogQ=select your gender!
    // Set up the buttons
     builder.setPositiveButton("Male", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
         userGender=Gender.MALE;//put value on mainClass proprty (userGender)
    synchronized (Thread.currentThread()){
        Thread.currentThread().notify(); // here is the POINT : resume the thread when selection done
        } } });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Female", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
         userGender=Gender.FEMALE;
         dialog.cancel();
         synchronized (Thread.currentThread()){
        Thread.currentThread().notify();}}});
        builder.show();// show dialogue and then pause the thread by next line
         try {
        synchronized( Thread.currentThread()){
        Thread.currentThread().wait();}
                    } catch......
    ....
```

this make may android program to halt And close

any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need all of the `Threads`, `synchronized`, etc... simply use [setCancelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setCancelable%28boolean%29) on your `AlertDialog.Builder`. This will force the user to select and option before continuing or closing the `Dialog`.

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SendRandom.this);
 builder.setTitle("gender");
 builder.setCancelable(false);  // here
 builder.setMessage(R.string.Gender_dialogQ); //Gender_dialogQ=select your gender!
 // Set up the buttons
 ...
```

Comment: the question, Does this stop the program from continue until the dialogue  dismiss??

Comment: Not necessarily depending on what you have but you can use `onDissmissListener` to run the code after it is closed

Comment: onDissmissListener and onClick is the same in my setuation, thu, Ever if I used (notify) in the onDissmissListener, its the same like I did, used (notify) in Onclick!

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand that sentence at all. If it is crashing then you need to post the logcat. But I don't see any reason for the `Thread` and `notify()`. Just call a function or run the code you want in your `onClick()`

Answer (score 0):

A Dialog would run on the UI thread, since a dialog IS a UI element.  So, i'm not sure what you're doing with the AsyncTask and the threading stuff.  Get rid of all that.

Comment: there is no way to pause main UI, so I try to pause my independent thread... due to I cannot continue without insure I get the User gender Its important for the continues ..

Comment: Does Thread.currentThread return a Thread of the main Layout?????? I am in AsyncTask mean I am not in the main layout

Comment: I see, the Asyc Is not thread so I replace "Currentthread"  with :
this, ad it has been "this.waite()"
but no new in the result!!